# How to change column values based on value of an index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

```
                                                                S/R
Batfast_id   Session_no   Event_Name   Overs  Deliveries_faced
bfs_1        1            fulham       0      5                  20
                                       1      11                 45
                                       2      17                 30
bfs_2        1            gps          0      5                  55
                                       1      11                 34
                                       2      17                 27
```

I have a df as above with a multi index of `Batfast_id, Session_no, Event_Name, Overs, Deliveries_faced`. I want to make the `S/R` = 0, everywhere `Deliveries_faced` is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['S/R'] = np.where(df['Deliveries_faced']==5, 0, df['S/R'])
```

This solution is not affected by index columns